# Print 100 Circles

Tags: code-golf

Goal: Create the smallest possible code to open a separate window, in which there are 100 circles of random sizes and colors.

Rules: All circles must be visible to the unassisted, naked eye, so in other words more than 2 pixels across, the background must be black, at least 5 different colors must be recognizable, and at all circles must fit within the window.

Comment: what do you mean by random sizes? what size should the window be? Can they be overlapping? Do the positions have to be random? Does it have to be filled or only have an outline?

Comment: Bash, 5 bytes. `feh f` Must be ran in a directory containg a file named 'f' that is an image containing 100 circles of random sizes and colors, and feh must be installed. This is technically not against the rules since their aren't any.

Comment: I like the challange but as it stands, this is way to broad. As @DrGreenEggsandHamDJ said, you should definitely think about some limiting rules.

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica 106 bytes

The code is fairly straightforward.  A palette is a floating window. The 100 circles are stored in an array. The first `r`yields coordinates; the second `r` yields a radius.

```
CreatePalette[{Graphics[Array[{RandomColor[],Disk[99~(r=RandomReal)~{2},r@5]}&,100],Background->Black]}]
```

[image: circles]

Answer (score 0):

### Java, 352 Bytes

Yeah, I know, an applet, but still...

```
import java.applet.*;import java.awt.*;import java.util.*;public class C extends Applet{public void paint(Graphics a){Random b=new Random();int x,y,diameter;setBackground(Color.black);for(int c=1;c<=100;c++){a.setColor(new Color(b.nextInt(0xFFFFFF)));d=b.nextInt(getWidth()/10);x1=b.nextInt(getWidth());y1=b.nextInt(getHeight());a.drawOval(x,y,d,d);}}}
```

Ungolfed Code:

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;

public class C extends Applet {
    public void paint(Graphics a) {

        Random b = new Random();

        int x, y, d;

        setBackground(Color.black);

        for (int c = 1; c <= 100; c++) {
            a.setColor(new Color(b.nextInt(0xFFFFFF)));

            d = b.nextInt(getWidth() / 10);
            x = b.nextInt(getWidth());
            y = b.nextInt(getHeight());

            a.drawOval(x, y, d, d);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: @EᴀsᴛᴇʀʟʏIʀᴋ Nope.

Comment: Have you tried using `Math.random()*getWidth()` in place of `b.nextInt(getWidth())`? It may save you a few bytes (you'd remove the `Random b` definition too)

Comment: how about c<101 rather than c<=100

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2 PIL - 199 bytes

Making some assumptions of the rules based on OP's answer. Not optimally golfed in the sense that the image could be 5 pixels across and the circles could be all the same place with grayscale colors, but goes with the spirit of the rules.

```
import Image,ImageDraw,random
h=999
i=Image.new('RGB',(h,h))
g=random.randint
exec"r,x,y=g(0,50),g(0,h),g(0,h);ImageDraw.Draw(i).ellipse((x-r,y-r,x+r,y+r),(g(0,255),g(0,255),g(0,255)));"*100
i.show()
```